# SQL alchemy apply a default filter on LIMIT query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In our code we have a before_compile method that runs on all queries and automatically add in some extra filters (based on current context) for multi-tenancy results on the same table. When we have a query that has a limit/offset in the original query when the before_compile hook runs and adds in the extra filter we get this error.

> Query.filter() being called on a Query which already has LIMIT or
> OFFSET applied. To modify the row-limited results of a Query, call
> from_self() first. Otherwise, call filter() before limit() or offset()
> are applied.

We have hooks in to be able to mark a query as one that doesnt get the generic filter in the compile hook applied to it and just have to ensure the proper multi-tenancy logic is applied to the query before the hook, but it would be nice to be able to rely on that hook for all the queries. Is there a way to apply a filter after a limit in that way? The from_self doesnt work in this case because it applies the limit to the query before the extra filtering is done, which could mean rows are limited from the original result set because of the limit, but then further rows are limited due to the extra filter added after the limit.

Here is the jist of the before_compile method we are running.

```
@event.listens_for(Query, "before_compile", retval=True)
def ensure_project_identified(query: Query):
    context = getattr(query, 'context', None)
    safe_mode = getattr(query, 'safe', True)
    if not safe_mode:
        return query
    # Logic to get partitioned entities based on their mixin classes. 
    for partitioned_entity in partitioned_models:
        _LOGGER.debug("Adding tenant id of %s qualifier to %s entity." % (context.tenant_id, str(partitioned_entity)))
        query = query.filter(partitioned_entity.tenant_id == context.tenant_id)
    return query
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a fix? See Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/jr9zw9/proper_handling_of_company_filters_with_before/

Comment: For all of my .first() queries I've replaced them with .one_or_none() to at least get through some of this impass

Comment: I haven't yet, right now I have implemented a custom query class that has an attribute on it to tell the before compile not to add in the extra filter and instead moved that same logic as in the before compile to the corresponding method. Unfortunately this kinda defeats the before compile written generically for all queries, but there's only a couple of those compared to the entire set of queries we have.

Comment: One thought I did have but haven't had the time to play with it is identifying the queries in the before compile that have a first or limit and doing some kind of copy to a new query, first copying the filters then applying the extra filter that's in the before compile, then applying the first/limit on it afterwords. Not sure how easy that would be to do with what's accessible on the query but that was going to be my next attempt to overcome it.

Comment: I ended up removing the event listener entirely. I used my CRUDMixin Model to grab the company_id from the JWT claims in a function and that pretty much solved it easily. Pro: It was simple and got the job done, Con: Instead of returning a 403 Forbidden error, I now return a 404 not found, which is fine 

    @classmethod
    def find_by_id(cls, _id):
        return cls.query.filter_by(id=_id, company_id=get_current_company()).one_or_none()